# How to disable TS errors on compile during development using NestJS

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs

Is there any way to disable TS errors on compile during development? In CRA there is a setting `TSC_COMPILE_ON_ERROR` that makes it possible. Didn't find anything to use with `NestJS`